# 2d Keyframe stays visible after adding new ones

Tags: keyframes, grease-pencil, 2d

I aded 41 keyframes by either plain drawing, duplicating or editing other keyframes, the thing is, when I try to add keyframe 42, the keyframe 41 appears on top of it, and this happens for every new keyframe I draw.

The only new thing I added was a new GP layer  above my original layer, and if I erase it, it also disappears from all previous keyframes.

I tried searching other questions with this issue but I don't seem to understand anything, I have some experience modeling and sculpting as well.

Also: this has nothing to do with onion skinning as these only appear when drawing new frames, not when hitting the spacebar.

[image: The original layer is sketches and the new one is called props cloth]

Comment: Onion skinning is precisely for showing the previous frames, on a lighter tone, so that you can get a sense of the progression of the motion.

Comment: I understand what onion skinning does, but onion skinning shouldn't show during rendering, my problem is that frame 41 keeps appearing in all subsequent frames. In the picture, the shoes are frame 41 on timeline 300, and I have 3 or 4 new frames after that, the shoes keep showing on top of everything no matter how many frames I add (and I'm drawing on a different layer), if I erase the shoes on frame 41, the shoes also dissapear in all previous frames.

Comment: could it be because you're drawing on a different layer? If so, you'd have to add a blank frame on the "shoe layer" when you want them to disappear